# In a 1-1 relationship, why is my insert inserting two records in two tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having trouble, as title says, when I `INSERT` a record in a table that has got a 1-1 relationship with another.

First things first, the SQL code that generates the tables:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Facebook_Info;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Conversations;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Conversations(
c_id        INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
c_start     TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
channel     ENUM('desktop', 'facebook'),

u_name      VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
u_email     VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(c_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Facebook_Info (
c_id        INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,

f_id        INT(12) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(c_id),
FOREIGN KEY(c_id) REFERENCES Conversations(c_id)
);
```

I assure you this code works: I tested it. I hope this is the best way to provide a 1-1 relationship between Conversations and Facebook_Info.

In any case, now I can introduce you my nightmare: I'm trying to insert a new record in Conversations via PHP (procedural style).

```
public function create_new_id_conv($channel = 1) {
    $w_ch = '';
    if ($channel == 2) {
        $w_ch = 'facebook';
    } else {
        $w_ch = 'desktop';
    }
    $query  = "INSERT INTO Conversations (c_id, c_start, channel) VALUES (NULL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'$w_ch')";
    $conn   = mysqli_connect("localhost", Wrapper::DB_AGENT, Wrapper::DB_PSW, Wrapper::DB_NAME);
    $res    = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $id_conv= mysqli_insert_id($conn);
    mysqli_free_result($res);
    return $id_conv;
}
```

The Wrapper:: * variables are all set well, in fact, an INSERT operation is done, **but not only one**! I'm having this situation after I call this function:

**This is the content of Conversations table:**

[image: This is the content of Conversations table]

**And here's the content of Facebook_Info:**

[image: And here's the content of Facebook_Info]

What's happening?

Comment: Removed sql server tag as this is clearly about mysql.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the advice

Comment: Just a guess, which is probably incorrect, but i think that FOREIGN KEY(c_id) REFERENCES Conversations(c_id) means that when you create something in one table, your key appears in another table.

Comment: @Dimi I checked right now. Thanks for the advice, but the result is still the same.

Comment: In Facebook_info, c_id should be a plain INT and f_id should be the AUTOINCREMENT and PRIMARY KEY. That way you have two independent tables linked on c_id. Right now if you added a record to Facebook_info before adding to Conversations then you would get a Foreign Key error because c_id wouldn't exist in Conversations yet.

Comment: No, it doesn't solve anything. Thanks anyway. Also, I can't put the f_id field as AUTO_INCREMENT, because the f_id has a value that comes from a request I perform to FB.

Comment: Well you have an actual value of 2147483647 and this isn't coming from nowhere. So you must have another query somewhere inserting that value into the facebook table.

Comment: I tried give myself a good answer to explain to others what happened.

Answer (score 0):

I searched and searched...

Then I started to think about what I'm getting here: **2147483647**. What represents this number? What's that? Seems like a big number!
And what if my script and my queries were correct but the mistake is the skeleton of my tables?

I must register a 14 digit integer, that is too large for the [INT type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html).

So using BIGINT to store the f_id field made all correct and working!

Hope my mistake helps someone!

Comment: Why did you think that using `bigint` solved the problem created by using `int(12)` ? Something else is there. Did you investigate what the real value was prior to insertion into the `Facebook_Info` table?

Comment: Absolutely yes, as I said in the answer: the f_id actually value is a unique 14 digit integer. 

If you try to declare an `INT(100)` (integer with 100 digits) SQL actually stores an integer that (by definition) can hold the max value, as a signed number, 2147483647, so a SIGNED INT OF 4 BYTES.